# Active Model Serializer not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've the folloing active model serializer but is not working as expected. 
`gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.x'`

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
  has_many :task
end
```

controller class method

```
def show
    user = User.find(params[:id]);
    render json:{status:'success', error:false, data:user},status: :ok
end
```

And model class

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

This gives the output

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "error": false,
    "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "full_name": "sohail ahmad",
        "email": "sohail1@gmail.com",
        "created_at": "2020-03-10T05:41:42.045Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-03-10T05:41:42.045Z"
    }
}
```

How I get only Id with serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are not using your UserSerializer in your controller. Your show method should be like this in order to serialize its data.

```rb
def show
    user = User.find(params[:id]);
    render json:{status:'success', error:false, data:UserSerializer.new(user)},status: :ok
end
```

Comment: and how I can access all data if I use has_many :task in UserSerializer?? right now I'm getting error if i use this

Comment: And there is little typo at UserSerializer. ```has_many :task``` should be ```has_many :tasks```

Comment: I did this but getting exception undefined method `tasks'

Comment: Your user class should be like this in order to have has_many relation
```ruby
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```